# segmentation fault(core dumped) on Ubuntu

Tags: c++

I have read few topics about same problem, but i can't find what's wrong in my code. This is header file:

```
#pragma once

class Queue
{
private:
    float *elements;
    int count;
    float newElement;

public:
    Queue();
    Queue(int);
    Queue(Queue &);
    ~Queue();   

    void enqueue(float);
    float dequeue();

    int getCount();
};
```

And .cpp file:

```
#include "Queue.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

Queue::Queue()
{}

Queue::Queue(int arrSize)
{

    this->count = arrSize;
    float *elements = new float[arrSize];

    for(int i = 0; i < arrSize - 1; i++)
    {
        newElement = rand()% 4000;
        newElement /= 100;
        elements[i] = newElement;
    }

}

void Queue::enqueue(float element)
{
    size_t newSize = count + 1;
    float *new_elements = new float[newSize];
    memcpy(new_elements, elements, newSize);

    count = newSize;
    delete [] elements;
    elements = new_elements;

    elements[count] = element;
}

float Queue::dequeue()
{
    float firstElement = elements[0];


    size_t newSize = count - 1;
    float *new_elements = new float[newSize];
    memcpy(new_elements, elements, newSize);

    count = newSize;
    delete [] elements;
    elements = new_elements;

    return firstElement;
}

int Queue::getCount()
{
    return count;
}

Queue::~Queue()
{
    delete [] elements;
}




int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    Queue queue(4);

    queue.enqueue(3);




}
```

I was trying to figure out where my mistake is, but I'm begginer in C++.
I think that something is wrong i my "dequeue" method, by after trying to fix it, it's still the same.

Comment: One thing I see is that the size passed to memcpy should be smallest of the size of the new array or the old array

Comment: That's a ridiculously dangerous and evil default constructor.

Comment: You didn't really ask a specific question. Why do you think something's wrong? What problem are you having? What precisely are you doing to get a segmentation fault? Did you get a core dump? Did you analyze it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several problems

- The default constructor doesn't initialize its members
- `Queue::Queue(int arrSize)` has a local variable `elements`, which shadows the member `elements`. The consequence, this constructor doesn't initialize its member
- `enqueue` should copy `count * sizeof(float)` bytes, not `newSize` bytes
- as @Vladimir noticed, `enqueue` assigns one element beyond the allocated memory. Should be `elements[count - 1] = element;`
- `dequeue` should copy `newSize * sizeof(float)` bytes, not `newSize` bytes

Comment: totally agree + final line in enqueue should work with elements[count -1]

Comment: Thanks, biggest problem was my constructor, where I don't know why I didn't used this->elements.